# Create a df from delimited values of each row in another df

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm looking to create a new pandas dataframe from each row in a given dataframe.
The values in the row are comma-delimited strings.

e.g. Input

```
COLUMN_1               COLUMN_2                      COLUMN_3
"Marvel"               "Hulk, Thor, Ironman"         "1,7,8"
"DC"                   "Spiderman, Batman, Flash"    "18, 74, 88"
```

Desired Output

```
COLUMN_1     COLUMN_2
Hulk                1
Thor                7
Ironman             8


COLUMN_1     COLUMN_2
Spiderman          18
Batman             74
Flash              88
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can using `groupby` with `str.split` and creat the target df you want

```
for x , y in df.groupby('COLUMN_1'):
    s=pd.DataFrame({'COLUMN_1':y.COLUMN_2.str.split(', ').iloc[0],'COLUMN_2':y.COLUMN_3.str.split(',').iloc[0]})
    print(s)
    COLUMN_1 COLUMN_2
0  Spiderman       18
1     Batman       74
2      Flash       88
  COLUMN_1 COLUMN_2
0     Hulk        1
1     Thor        7
2  Ironman        8
```

Also we can store the data into a dict

```
d={x:pd.DataFrame({'COLUMN_1': y.COLUMN_2.str.split(', ').iloc[0], 'COLUMN_2': y.COLUMN_3.str.split(',').iloc[0]})  for x, y in df.groupby('COLUMN_1')}
d
Out[412]: 
{'DC':     COLUMN_1 COLUMN_2
 0  Spiderman       18
 1     Batman       74
 2      Flash       88, 'Marvel':   COLUMN_1 COLUMN_2
 0     Hulk        1
 1     Thor        7
 2  Ironman        8}
```